# Babel - Difference between languages

Tags: babel, languages

This simple file that shows an error in English and compiles just fine under Portuguese:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[portuges]{babel}

\begin{document}
\ro
\end{document}
```

Why would `\ro` be defined in one language and not on the other? How does one find out what is  `\ro` defined to in Portuguese? What other commands are defined in this way? There is no mentioning of `\ro` in the Babel manual.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Type ª and º from the keyboard and be happy. All the rest is pure verbiage.

Answer (score 5):

> How does one find out what is `\ro` defined to in Portuguese?

To find out how a command is defined, use `\show`. Running `\show\ro` and looking in the log file, one finds:

```
> \ro=macro:
->$^{\rm o}$.
l.8 \show\ro
```

This says that (a) `\ro` is a macro, not a TeX primitive; (b) its definition comes down to `\def\ro{$^{\rm o}$}`; and (c) it's supposed to be used in text mode, not math mode.

I'm no expert in Portuguese, but I believe that "first, second, third" is written in long form as "primeiro, segundo, terceiro" and, using LaTeX/babel input notation, as `1\ro, 2\ro, 3\ro` in short-hand. Given the definition of `\ro` shown above, I will let you guess what the output of `1\ro, 2\ro, 3\ro` looks like.

Clearly, then, `\ro` is meant to be used to "convert" (in a typographical sense!) a cardinal number into an ordinal number. Observe that while `\ro` does not take an explicit argument, it isn't meant to be used by itself but, rather, in conjunction with a numeral.

Incidentally, Portuguese knows both masculine-form and feminine-form ordinals; to generate "primeira, segunda, terceira, quarta" in abbreviated form, one would input them as `1\ra, 2\ra, 3\ra, 4\ra`. E.g., "a quarta vez" ("the fourth time") might be abbreviated as `a 4\ra~vez`.

> Why would `\ro` be defined in one language and not [in] the other?

Ummm, because typographic needs differ across languages?

For sure, in English-language typesetting there is no apparent need for either the `\ro` or the `\ra` macro. "First, second, third" are *definitely not* written in abbreviated form as `1\textsuperscript{o}, 2\textsuperscript{o}, 3\textsuperscript{o}` in an English-language document. Moreover, English doesn't feature a distinction between masculine and feminine (let alone neutral!) ordinals.

There are several LaTeX packages that simplify and standardize the typesetting of ordinal numbers. One such package is [Nicola Talbot's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) [fmtcount](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount), which provides the macro `\ordinalnum` and which features a large number of language-specific adaptations. (Aside: The `fmtcount` package provides many other facilities besides the macro `ordinalnum`...) Sure enough,

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{report}
\usepackage{babel,fmtcount}
\begin{document}
1\ro, \ordinalnum{1}, 2\ra, \ordinalnum{2}[f]
\end{document}
```

twice produces the numeral "1" followed by a superscript-level scriptsize letter "o", as well as two instances of the numeral "2" followed by a superscript-level scriptsize letter "a". (I will let you guess what `\ordinalnum{2}` produces if `babel` is loaded with the option `english`.)

It's useful to remind oneself that the `babel` package has been around for a long time and hence that many of `babel`'s language-specific typesetting facilities were created long before the advent of packages such as `fmtcount`. For sure, the language-specific heterogeneity one finds in `babel` at present is far greater than if the package were written from scratch today in a top-down manner. (Aside: If the `portuges` module of `babel` were written today, one would probably also replace `\def\ro{$^{\rm o}$}` and `\def\ra{$^{\rm a}$}` with `\def\ro{\textsuperscript{o}}` and `\def\ra{\textsuperscript{a}}`, respectively, but that's a different issue.)

Comment: To add to the answer, there is also a `\ra` defined as superscript `a`, the feminine form.

Comment: @Cicada - Excellent suggestion! I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would generally recommend against using legacy commands from `babel` definition files.

The [standard commands for this](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) are `\textordmasculine` and `\textordfeminine`.  These work in any language and do not require `babel`.

You can also type in the characters ª and º into your editor the same way you normally would.  They will work in any recent version of LaTeX.

All of these commands are for text mode.  If for some reason you want to use them in math mode, you would need to wrap the word in a command such as `\textnormal{1º}`.  This switches back to text mode.

On modern versions of PDFTeX, all of these commands should work by default.  On older installations, you might need to add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

On LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you instead want to enable modern fonts with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

Followed by `\setmainfont`.  Many font packages will set up the encodings for you correctly, though.

Some fonts have a bar underneath these symbols, and others do not, so pick one that fits your preference.  If you want a version with no underline, along with a font that gives them one, you could redefine

```
\renewcommand\textordmasculine{\textsuperscript{o}}
\renewcommand\textordfeminine{\textsuperscript{a}}
```

Comment: Because `\textordmasculine` and `\textordfeminine` insert a bar below `o` and `a`, respectively, they're suitable for French documents -- as French typography employs the underlining convention -- but less so for Portuguese documents -- as Portuguese typographic practice does not appear to underline the raised letters "o" and "a". I would advocate that `\ra` and `\ro` be redefined in babel's `portuges` module as `\textsuperscript{a}` and `\textsuperscript{o}`, respectively. That way, the macros "work" if a sans-serif text font is in use -- as is usually the case in `beamer` documents.

Comment: @Mico That depends entirely on the font. Computer Modern chooses to have a bar underneath, but many other fonts don’t. For example, Libertine.

Comment: @Mico It’s certainly possible to `\renewcommand\textordmasculine{\textsuperscript{o}}`, however.

Comment: @Mico For what it’s worth, Wikipedia claims that underlining ordinals is mandatory in Brazilian Portuguese and recommended in Portugal.

Comment: @Mico I’m not sure which French style guide you’re thinking of, since French ordinals do not end in  *-o* or *-a*.

Comment: I guess I wasn't thinking of "premier, seconde, troisième" but, rather, of "primo", "secondo", "tertio", which translate into "first, second, third". These words are used as counters in a listing -- very much in the sense of "First, ...", "Second, ...", and "Third, ...". Is there a name for these words? They don't seem to be "ordinary" ordinals [pun intended]. At any rate, I believe they can be abbreviated as `1\textordmasculine`, `2\textordmasculine`, etc. You're absolutely right that `\textordfeminine` doesn't come into play here.

Comment: @Mico When I went to look it up, I noticed that the *Trésor de la Langue Française informatisé* writes the abbreviation Nº with no line below the º. I don’t know how common it is to have one in print.

Comment: @Mico And I think *primo*, and English *firstly* or “First, do this,” are called ordinal adverbs.

Comment: Many thanks for providing the term "ordinal adverb". :-) For sure, I should have phrased my initial comment in terms of Italian or Spanish typographic practice rather than in terms of French typographic practice.

Comment: @Davislor, Wikipedia is wrong on that count. It's just a habit, there's no law or grammatical rule for that either in Brazil or in Portugal.

Comment: @BlackBird Thank you! I don’t know Portuguese, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Several language definition files for `babel` are poorly documented.

If you do [`texdoc babel-portuges`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.pdf) (on a terminal or clicking the link), you will see, at the very end,

[image]

despite the LDF file is claimed to have been very recently revised. I guess that these definitions have been added long ago, at the very beginning of `babel` history. Several LDFs have similar *ad hoc* definitions for various languages and it's really a nuisance, because they could conflict with user or package commands.

Say you define in your English document a command named `\ord` or `\ro` (the former could be used for a math operator, for instance): the command will work good. Upon adding `\usepackage[portuges]{babel}`, however, compilation would stop: a document such as

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}

%[...]
```

would stop with

```latex
! LaTeX Error: Command \ord already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.6 \DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}
```

Are there workarounds? Note that removing these definitions from `portuges.ldf` would break existing documents in Portuguese using `\ord`, `\orda`, `\ro` or `\ra`.

But for *your* document, you can look up in the specific document what the offending command means and decide whether you need or not. For instance, with `\ord`, you could add a workaround such as

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[portuges]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% fix an incompatibility
\let\babelord\ord
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ord}{%
  \ifmmode\expandafter\ordop\else\expandafter\babelord\fi
}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ordop}{ord}

%[...]
```

because the original `\ord` only belongs to text mode.